# Why can I not publish from -QGIS Geoserver plugin?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, boundless-suite

I am following the tutorial at http://qgis.boundlessgeo.com/static/docs/quickstart.html and I get to the step "To publish the project as it is, just select the QGIS project entry in the OpenGeo Explorer tree, and then click Publish.... You will see the following dialog:"

But 'Publish' is greyed out.

One oddity is that when I Add a Geoserver Catalogue I get a warning: Warning: Could not connect to the catalog at that URL

But I don't understand what this means.  Is there something else I need to configure on GeoServer?

Comment: I think this means that I don't have CWS plugin installed. The install instructions <http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/csw/installing.html>are broken but I found the download here: <http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/release/2.5/plugins/geoserver-2.5-csw-plugin.zip>. The next instruction is "Extract this file and place the JARs in WEB-INF/lib."

I don't know where "WEB_INF" is?

Comment: Found WEB-INF by using find.  There is one for each member of the suite so I unpacked it in the geoserver one and restarted geoserver but the geoserver admin interface still does not list CWS service.  I have contacted Bounldessgeo support since they sent me a nice note asking how I was going ;)